# C# Application is written with .Net Framework 4.0 But It Requires .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, .net-4.6.2

I have a 2 WPF application uses `.Net Framework 4.0` and suddlenly one of them started to require `.Net Frameowork 4.6.2` in my clients `Windows 7` computers. In properties Target Framework is still `4.0`.

I checked my commits, a while ago I changed 2 things in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

1. `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` to `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`
2. `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]` to `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it works when users remove `.exe.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

but still I don't understand why `VS` creates this file.